# magento admin not clickable except dashboard

Tags: magento-2.0

I have installed Magento-CE-2.0.0+Samples-2015-11-17-06-11-18
but after installing in admin side all the sections except dashboard is disabled, it not clickable. can anyone guide me regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Before that take **Backup**

Remove everything, except `.htaccess` file from `pub/static folder`

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path `“Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink”` and replace to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`

Note: Remove entire files and folder under `pub/stati`c except `.htaccess` file.

For More info ref this http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: is it good to edit core file and replace Symlink with Copy ? it will be problem while future upgrade

Comment: Please Before that take Backup. I think it's not affect you  took backup